# I'm trying to create a button with wxPython but it doesn't appear in the output frame, where am I wrong?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I'm new in wxpython module and I have a macOS Sierra, I'm trying to create a button, but it doesn't appear, furthermore I can't change the background color of panels, so I think that the problem is in the definition of panels, how can I fix it?

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame=MyFrame(None,-1,title="Henry")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __int__(self,parent,id,title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent,id,title)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK) # it doesn't work
        self.button=wx.Button(self.panel,label="premi",pos=(40,40))  # it doesn't work


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The output of the script is only the default frame.

Comment: You need a sizer (simple `BoxSizer` should do here) or actually two (one for the frame, one for the panel). Sizers are responsible for layout of child components.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you typoed the name of your `MyFrame.__init__` method. You named it `__int__`, so it is not called when you create an instance of `MyFrame`.

Comment: Yes it works, I didn’t see it. Thank you very much.